# AND operator between some columns of one table

Tags: mysql, sql

With a serious of join, I have this table, in witch the rows are the name of a author, the title of his book, and the id of the book. If a book has two or more authors, there are two or more rows.

```
+------------+------+--------+
| AuthorName | book | idBook |
+------------+------+--------+
| a1         | b1   |      1 |
| a2         | b1   |      1 |
| a3         | b2   |      2 |
| a4         | b2   |      2 |
| a5         | b2   |      2 |
+------------+------+--------+
```

Now I want to create a filter in witch if a user insert the authors, he'll get the title of a combinations of the inserted authors. For example:
If I insert "a1" and "a2", I'll get b1. But if I insert "a1" and "a3", I'll get a empty string, because there isn't a combination between this two authors.

How can I write a query for this problem? I've tried something like:

```sql
select AuthorName, book, idBook
from table
where AuthorName = a1 and AuthorName = a2
```

But obviously it doesn't work because the result is a empty string.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select book, idBook
from t
where AuthorName in ('a1', 'a2')
group by book, idbook
having count(*) = 2;  -- number of elements in the list
```

Note:  You should not be storing `book` in this table.  `bookid` should be a foreign key reference to a table, such as `books`, where `bookid` is the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is only a exemple table for explaining my problem. Actually this is a result of a join between more tables, in witch there is the table of the books too. But with this solution, if a user search 3 authors, and in the query there will be "where AuthorName in ('a1', 'a2','a3')", the result is not a empty string. can i say why do you insert in the query "having count(*) = 2"?

Comment: @Brododipollo . . . for three authors, the `2` would be `3`.